# Ng-href Not Working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-href

I have this code

```
<a ng-href="{{vm.user.quicklinks2}}" ><image src="./images/potato.jpeg"></a>
```

Which when hovered over shows nothing

whereas this works

```
<a href="{{vm.user.quicklinks2}}" ><image src="./images/potato.jpeg"></a>
```

And i have set $compileProvider in my config as follows

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
```

I have looked everywhere and have not been able to find a solution. {{vm.user.quicklinks2}} returns a correct value.

Comment: Does it just not show a link on hover or does it not actually go where you want it to when you click it?

Comment: It does not go anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

just combine the two

is a normal link with href and nothing about AngularJs